# Custom XAML Applications (non-WPF and non-WWF)

Tags: xaml, project-template

This question is likely a particular XAML application. XAML is a custom markup to instantiate objects and, as such, define custom applications. Note that, it serves to both declare WPF user interfaces and WWF workflows. It would also help to specify, e.g., a custom source-code change detection solution. To avoid getting in deeper in unnecessary details. I need to design a custom XAML-based model that, like the one for WPF and the one for WWF do, allows me to declare a custom application on top of XAML, without having to create a WPF or WWF project. Is this sort of third-part XAML-like provider possible to build?

```
<Approach>
  <PrimitiveExample
    OriginalType={Type syntax:LiteralSyntax} 
    ModifiedType={Type syntax:LiteralSyntax}
    Propagation.Matched={Binding MatchedPropagationCommand}>
    ...
  </PrimitiveExample>
...
<Approach/>
```

Let us see it this way. Is there a way to get a stand-alone XAML file that works as follows?

a) There will be a project item, e.g., named "Stand-alone XAML".

b) I create a new "Stand-alone XAML" item named, e.g., "Solution.sccd", and I add it to a console application, class library, or many other projects. This because it will be a sort of smart .config.

c) I can set up a root instance in "Solution.sccd" (likely containing a lot of nested instances) - this is natural for XAML.

d) When declaring instances in "Solution.sccd", I can use features like attached properties, binding, and many other smart features or markup extensions that can be used with WPF or WWF, but this will not be a WPF or WWF project.

e) I can instantiate the declared root instance, e.g., with simple code line like "var rootObject = XAMLInstanceCreator.Create(Solution.sccd)", and use that object.

Does this make sense now?

Regards, Guillermo.

Comment: What kind of answers do you expect? As WPF is open sourced, you can reuse its XAML engine for whatever purposes you like, so I doubt how this can "make no sense".

Comment: I found this excerpt from the book "XAML Developer Reference". 

"XAML Services: .... You can extend the XAML type system functionality of XAML representations into specific features enabled by a framework, an application, and so on that accept and render XAML. The XAML type
system provides the APIs required to work with the nodes of a XAML node stream."

It seems what I need is to implement a custom XAML application on top of the XAML Services (a sort of XAML subset), and finally defining a custom item template.